# How to get iFrame src content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iFrame, content of which is inside another iFrame. I want to get the inside iFrame's `src` content. How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: Is what you're trying to do allowed by the same-origin rule?

Comment: what i am expecting is if i have an iframe inside another iframe then how can get the inner iframe's src?

Comment: Is the page in the inner iframe on the same host as your page?

Comment: yes. both the pages are in same host and same root.

Comment: Are you asking for the value of the src attribute or the value of the contents of the page?

Comment: only the value of the iframe content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer page:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="ifr1" src="page1.htm"></iframe>
<iframe id="ifr2" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.htm:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(parent.document.getElementById('ifr2').src);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

iframeInstance.contentWindow.document - this document loaded from SRC url.
and vice verse - to get from inner document to parent use:
parent.document

Comment: i got src of outer iframe. if i want the inner iframe src how can i get ? can u pls give me an example regarding my question ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div id="f1" style="padding-left:5px;">..</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("f1").innerHTML = '<iframe src="frame.php or html" width="200" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not so expert but this for your script hints, you can modify and test for your pages.

Answer (score 0):

In a desktop application special usecase there was a need to executeScript in the browser engine to fill out some inputs unattended by data base driven content..

step A) get the page src usually displayed as an iframe within another iframe

```
var newUrl = document.getElementById('iframeNestedFirst').contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframeExternalNestedWithinFirst').src;
```

step B) open that detected url including runtime tokens on a new page

```
window.open(newUrl).focus();        or       window.open(newUrl,'_blank').focus();
```

Now you might get access to the DOM of that - as foreseen as an iframe - content of the different domain, when loaded as a new document.