# jQuery access DOM element

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancynox with an iframe and html document with form in it.
I try to access the form's parent DOM element.
The form's id is "form"
I tried:

```
$("#form").get(0).parentNode    
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').getElementById('form')  //TypeError  
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').document  //undefined
```

How can I access the form?

Comment: `$("#form")` accesses the form element, what specifically do you need to do ?

Comment: append a child node after the form. I think $("#form") is not a DOM node.

Comment: Check this thread - [How to get iFrame src content using javascript?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264569/how-to-get-iframe-src-content-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

> http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Answer (score 1):

$('#form') is the form in your case.  It is the jQuery node, however, so you need to use jQuery functions on it...

Refer to the jQuery docs for more help on selectors and the available API
[jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Also, if you are using jQuery, you don't need to do all of the 'getElementById' stuff, as you can just access everything through jQuery selectors.

```
//A couple selector examples
$('#id')  //By Id
$('.class') //By Class
$('tag')  //By element tag
$('#id').next() //Get next element
$('#id').children() //list of child nodes
$('#id').find('#id2') //element id2 somewhere inside id1
```

For completeness, Here are some api examples

```
$('#id').css('background','red')  //Change background to red
$('#id').submit()  //if id element is a form, submit it
$('#id').val()  //if id element is an input, get its value
$('#id').text() //the text of an element
$('#id').hide() //hide the element
$('#id').show() //show the element
```