# Reading contents of an iframe with wikipedia source?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am developing an app in js. i need to read and parse html contained in dynamically changing iframe src. iframe src always points to a wikipedia article. i tried reading simple html source with methods described in other solutions here n it worked:

[How to get iFrame src content using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264569/how-to-get-iframe-src-content-using-javascript)

[How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

but i am not able to read any wikipedia article in the frame source!
help me out please!! thnk...
below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt(){
    alert($("#ifr").contents().find("body").html());
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="showIt()">Click here</a><br />
<iframe id="ifr" name="ifr" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframeWindow = top.frames['ifr'];
iframeWindow.onload=function(){alert('here');iframeContent=iframeWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

};
</script>
</html>
```

my question is different from [Query Wikipedia's API using AJAX (XMLHttpRequest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374377/query-wikipedias-api-using-ajax-xmlhttprequest)

I know this wikimedia's API and i also know how to use it! but it doesnt serve my purpose. this API returns article in plain text format encoded in JSON.

But what i want is articles formatted in HTML! I know how to do it in PHP. But i wanna do it in JS! Just help me with reading the HTML source of an iframe containing WP article. I know how to manipulate the content then.

---

OK.I read the "Same origin policy". It cant be done :P . 
CLOSED.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @SLaks: Is this redeemable, or can I close it as Too Localized?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's not too localized; it's just almost fully answered by that Wikipedia article.

Comment: @SLaks: Is there a way around it?

Comment: Yes; http://stackoverflow.com/q/2374377/34397